# Can excel set ranges from blank to blank in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of numbers in excel that are separated by blanks. Each group of numbers (between blanks) varies in quantity so the first group may have 5 numbers, the next 2 numbers, the next 6. I need to have excel select each group so I can run a formula to extract the largest number and the smallest number from each group. I know about min/max but don't know how to get excel to go from blank to blank setting ranges.

Comment: Please post some sample data so we can see what you have in mind.

Comment: The answer to your question is; yes it can.  But we need more specifics if we are going to help.  In your original post, put some example data and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a similar formula to this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",ROW(A1)=1),MAX(A2:INDEX($A2:$A$18,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($A2:$A$18="",0),0))),"")
```

So with the data in column A and the max in Column B:

[image]